# Can I use my auto-generated SO gravatar in other places?

Tags: support, gravatar

I have an auto-generated gravatar as my display on SO. I wish to associate that unique, but non-descriptive, gravatar in other places (such as github). I have grown rather fond of it. Is there anyway to do this? Do I have to go to [gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com) and actually sign up for an account?

Comment: It's a Gravatar. This is not SO specific. Any website which uses Gravatars will show the exact same one, provided you use the same email address.

Comment: @Bart that's an answer ;) You should post it as one

Comment: Speaking of gravatars, it's always a little weird for me when I see your posts, because ours basically differ only in saturation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gravatars are generated based on hashed values of your email addresses. It has been explained in details on Gravatar's [Creating Hash](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/) page.

1. Trim leading and trailing whitespace from an email address
2. Force all characters to lower-case
3. md5 hash the final string

As long as you keep using the same email address, you'll have the same image generated. In your case, the image is:

[image]

and the hashed value will be: **`e328e5547ae249f222721cba4a7010eb`**

Comment: Well, it turns out the email associated with the gravatar is different than what I though it was.  Many moons ago when my SO account was created I think I had some sort of account confusion.  So now I just have to get github to take that gravatar email and pop that image in.  Maybe it will show up after a little bit of a wait?

Comment: @demongolem There are [7 types of default images](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/) Gravatar provides. Stack Overflow uses `identicon` among them.